# Syntax error, concatenate string inside array

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my User model file I want to define rules for validation.

```
public function getUserID(){
    return Auth::id();
}

private $rules = array(
    'name' => 'required|alpha|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,' . $this->getUserID(),

);
```

I get

```
      FatalErrorException in User.php line 162: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'
```

I have included: use Auth;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fill `$rules` in your method __construct.
It is dangerous to use `$this` in a declaration, since the object may not exist...